# Pro*C can't force parallel DML while sqlplus can?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus, oracle-pro-c

Whenever I issue 'alter session force parallel DML;' from Pro*C I get an error. Although, it works fine from sqlplus for the same user. Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't directly related to Pro*C.  The error `ORA-12841: Cannot alter the session parallel DML state within a transaction` happened in Pro*C because it had already performed DML, whereas a new SQL*Plus session did not.  Moving the `COMMIT` or the `ALTER` statement should resolve the issue.

Thanks to Hemant K Chitale and €$ħ₪ on the Oracle Forum: https://community.oracle.com/message/10002348

Comment: Thanks. Great find. I will try putting it further up in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the trailing semicolon `';'` is part of the SQL statement?

Usually it only tells sqlplus that the SQL statement end here, but the semicolon is not part of the SQL syntax (except for PL/SQL)

Comment: This is how I write it in Sqlplus and in Pro*c I only add EXEC SQL at the beginning so the semicolon is pretty much there anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is Pro*C is execution. But if it Adds `BEGIN` and `END;`, then you must use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Comment: You can write plain sql in Pro*c just preceded by EXEC SQL.